# How to do arithmetic on date components in R

Tags: r, date

I'm trying to compute a function of date components (year, month, day). I am reading data into a data frame, parsing the strings into dates, and then, I hope, doing some arithmetic on the components of the dates.

Here is my data file:

```
timestamp,value
"2014-01-23 12:30:00",123
"2015-11-30 15:45:00",456
"2016-07-29 09:15:00",789
```

Here is my R session: (I am working with R 3.0.2 on Ubuntu 14.04)

```
> x <- read.csv ("foo.csv", row.names=NULL, header=T)
> x
            timestamp value
1 2014-01-23 12:30:00   123
2 2015-11-30 15:45:00   456
3 2016-07-29 09:15:00   789
> x1 <- as.vector (x[, 1])
> x1
[1] "2014-01-23 12:30:00" "2015-11-30 15:45:00" "2016-07-29 09:15:00"
> x1.t <- strptime (x1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
> x1.t
[1] "2014-01-23 12:30:00" "2015-11-30 15:45:00" "2016-07-29 09:15:00"
> x1.t.combo <- sapply (x1.t, function (t) { (t$year - 114)*12 + (t$mon + 1) })
Error in t$year : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Applying the `$` to elements of `x1.t` seems to work as expected, e.g. `(x1.t[1]$year - 114)*12 + (x1.t[1]$mon + 1)` yields `1`. What is causing the error message?

I find that `(x1.t$year - 114)*12 + (x1.t$mon + 1)` yields `1 23 31` as expected, so I guess it's not really necessary to figure out the business with `sapply`, but I'd still like to know, in the interest of understanding what's going on.

Comment: Firstly, `sapply` seems to be the wrong thing to be using here. Secondly, I can't see how `x1.t[1]$year` could possibly work. Try loading `library(lubridate)` and using `year(x1.t)` for example. So `x1.t.combo <- 12*(year(x1.t) - 114) + month(x1.t) + 1`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. (1) If you want to suggest a function other than `sapply`, I will give it a try. (2) Well, `x1.t[1]$year` just works -- you can't argue with success, as they say ... (3) Thanks for pointing out lubridate -- I will certainly give that a try.

Comment: @Hugh Thanks for suggesting lubridate. When I try `year(x1.t[[3]])`, I get: `Error in as.POSIXlt.numeric(x, tz = tz(x)) : 'origin' must be supplied`. However, `origin` doesn't appear to be an argument of `year`. How can I resolve that error? Maybe `origin` needs to be supplied when strings are parsed into dates? But as it stands, the parsing succeeds without `origin`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're running into is that POSIXlt itself is a type with multiple elements, so the *apply commands apply the function to each element of it. You can see the elements by `unlist(x1.t)`.

So you have to "go around" it. There's a simple way, where you don't have to convert it first:

```
> x <- c("2014-01-23 12:30:00", "2015-11-30 15:45:00")
> x
[1] "2014-01-23 12:30:00" "2015-11-30 15:45:00"
> y <- sapply (x, function (t) { t <- as.POSIXlt(t); (t$year - 114)*12 + (t$mon + 1) })
> y
2014-01-23 12:30:00 2015-11-30 15:45:00 
                  1                  23
```

But if you really want to convert it first, then you have to turn it into either numeric or character first and then once again convert back inside the function. Something like this:

```
> x <- c(strptime("2014-01-23 12:30:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), strptime("2015-11-30 15:45:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
> x
[1] "2014-01-23 12:30:00 EET" "2015-11-30 15:45:00 EET"
> y <- sapply (as.numeric(x), function (t) { t <- as.POSIXlt(t, origin = "1970-01-01"); (t$year - 114)*12 + (t$mon + 1) })
> y
[1]  1 23
```

Comment: Good heavens, I'm more confused now than when I started ... (1) "POSIXlt itself is a type with multiple elements, so the *apply commands apply the function to each element of it" -- if the first argument of `sapply` is a list of POSIXlt items, why isn't each item passed to the function an instance of POSIXlt? (2) What is the function of  `t <- as.POSIXlt(t)`? I thought `t` was already an instance of POSIXlt. (3) "if you really want to convert it first" -- well, I don't really want to convert it, or not convert it -- in what circumstances would I want one or the other? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hehe, yeah, well, it's somewhat confusing. 1) I don't know, I'm not that familiar with it. 2) that code is meant to work as a copy-paste. as you can see, the first block of my code doesn't do conversion outside of the function. 3) then ignore the 2nd block and just go with the first. You'd want to do conversions if you wanted to find out date differences for example.

Answer (score 2):

Both `sapply` and `lapply` yield the same error because `x1.t` is a list and they are passing the elements in the list one by one. The first one is a 3-element (atomic, not recursive) vector of seconds

```
> x1.t[[1]]   # same as x1.t[['sec']]
[1] 0 0 0
```

....and furthermore it (and all the other components) are being passed with no name. So even the year element which is the 5th or 6th list will still not have a name of 'year' by the time it gets to the body of that anonymous function.

```
dput(x1.t)
structure(list(sec = c(0, 0, 0), min = c(30L, 45L, 15L), hour = c(12L, 
15L, 9L), mday = c(23L, 30L, 29L), mon = c(0L, 10L, 6L), year = 114:116, 
    wday = c(4L, 1L, 5L), yday = c(22L, 333L, 210L), isdst = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L), zone = c("PST", "PST", "PDT"), gmtoff = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), .Names = c("sec", "min", "hour", 
"mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst", "zone", "gmtoff"
), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt"))
```

This is akin to the error people make when they think that the first element in a data.frame is the first row or that the length of a data.frame is the number of cases (when it is actually the number of columns.)

Comment: "x1.t is a list and they are passing the elements in the list one by one" -- that seems very strange; I expected the mapping function to pass in each element of `x1.t` as an aggregate. Why isn't the argument `t` received by the function an instance of POSIXlt? I'm extrapolating the behavior of mapping functions in other languages, and it appears that mapping functions in R behave in substantially different way. That's OK, although a bit of a surprise. Thanks for your informative comments.

Comment: I agree the behavior is not as one would expect. The POSIXlt structure is a very weird one. You are almost always better off using POSIXct, which is more likely to behave in the manner one would expect (modulo how you think about how it handles timezones which continues to confuse the heck out of me.)

Comment: Well, I'm more confused about sapply than about POSIXlt -- I would expect the mapping function to hand off elements of the first argument to the function, but it appears that it's actually handing off parts of elements. Right? If not, then what is the right way to look at what sapply is doing?

Comment: Both sapply and lapply are handing off the individual lists that are within that POSIXlt object. It's built as a set of lists.  It's as if you were working with a dataframe and tried to use it to pass individual rows. You would experience a similar confusion.

Comment: OK, I see now that sapply and lapply are handing off all the years, all the months, all the days, etc, instead of all the fields for the first element, all the fields for the second element, etc.; if one writes out the fields as columns and the elements as rows, then sapply and lapply are mapping over columns instead of rows, and that's what's surprising to me. Is there a mapping function which will map by elements instead of fields? `apply(as.matrix(x1.t), 1, function (t) { ... })` seems close, but `t$year` and `t$mon` within the function fail with "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors".

Comment: I see now that my surprise stems in large part from `strptime` returning a POSIXlt object with lists assigned to fields instead of a list of POSIXlt objects with simple values assigned to fields. I assumed that `strptime(x1, ...)` would be in effect the same as `lapply (x1, function (s) { strptime (s, ...) })` and that's not the case.